# How to join an array of strings without using .join()?

Tags: javascript

We're trying to write a function that takes an array of strings and a separator, and joins all the strings separated by such separator.

We are not allowed to use the .join() method.

So far, I'm stuck trying to iterate though all the strings adding a separator between them each time.

I tried something like:

```
var aName = ['Frank','Vincent','Zappa'];


var join = (arr, separator = " ") => {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        return arr[i] + separator + arr[i+1];
    }
};

join(aName, ' '); 

//output: "Frank Vincent"
//expected output: "Frank Vincent Zappa"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the for loop try with i<= arr.length

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow :). Your loop looks like it access elements out of bounds. Also, the logic of `arr[i] + separator + arr[i+1];` will cause items to be repeated. Perhaps initalise a sting to the first element and the loop over the remaining elements and appending `separator + arr[i]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your current code, try concatenating instead, and `return` only at the end:

```js
var aName = ['Frank', 'Vincent', 'Zappa'];


var join = (arr, separator = " ") => {
  let result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (result) {
      result += separator;
    }
    result += arr[i];
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(join(aName, ' '));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Everyone has been helpful, but this one takes the cake for showing me what I was doing wrong most clearly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the array:

```
function join(arr, separator)
{
    return arr.reduce((str, a)=> {return a+separator+str})
}
```

Comment: `const join = (arr, sep = " ") => arr.reduce((str, acc) => acc + sep + str);` for a one-liner better using arrow function semantics :D

Comment: Actually I had an inkling that I could use reduce, but I had no idea how to even begin conceptualizing it. This is very cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [String constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

```js
var name = ['Frank', 'Vincent', 'Zappa'];
console.log(String(name).replace(/,/g,' '))
```

Comment: @chiragRavindra, you can replace(',','') it with empty space

Comment: Though the array itself can contain strings containing commas @Chidambaram  :)

Comment: @Chidambaram like this? `const join = (arr = [], sep=' ') => String(arr).replace(/,/g,sep)`. But this oly works if the array items don't contain strings

Answer (score 2):

A very simple method is to append the separator only for the second element onwards:

```js
const arr = ["Frank", "Vincent", "Zappa"];

const join = (arr, sep = " ") => {
  if (!arr || !arr.length) return "";
  let ret = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ret += sep + arr[i];
  }
  return ret;
};

console.log(join(arr));
console.log(join(arr, "-"));
```

Comment: Perfect except when `arr` is empty.

Comment: @Amadan there, though I am sure there is a lot more error handling that could be done. OP's task really :) Also I'm not sure that the point of OP's exercise is to handle all edge cases such as calling `join` on a non-array…

Comment: Hey, why :) Now it's perfect. :D

Answer (score 1):

You could check the length of the array first and return an empty string if length is zero.

Otherwise take the first element as start value for the result and iterate from the second element and add the separator and the value of the array.

Proceed until no more elements. Then return the result string.

```js
var join = (array, separator = ' ') => {
        if (!array.length) return '';
        var result = array[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            result += separator + array[i];
        }
        return result;
    },
    array = ['Frank', 'Vincent', 'Zappa'];

console.log(join(array, ' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you use `return` in a `for` loop which means that function will stop it's execution and return a value you write in `return`.

To avoid that you should write something like this:

```
var name = ['Frank','Vincent','Zappa'];


var join = (arr, separator = " ") => {
    var result = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // adding to result string arr[i] and separator
        result += arr[i] + separator;       
    }
    // deleting separator in the end of string
    return result.slice(0, -1);
};

join(name, ' ');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I realize now my mistake in returning something inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise it is not possible to create a string without `join()` since JavaScript will internally always call `join()` for arrays. But if you just want to create your own `join()` function you can iterate through the array, add a separator to your current item and do this until you reached the end where you only add your current item without a separator.

```js
var name = ['Frank', 'Vincent', 'Zappa'];

function join(arr, separator = " ") {
    var str = "";

    if (arr.length === 0) return str;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        str += i !== arr.length - 1 ?
            arr[i] + separator :
            arr[i];
    }

    return str;
};

console.log(join(name, ' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a curried function in es2015

```js
const joinStrings = glue = ' ' => strings => {
  let res = '';
  strings.forEach(str => res += glue + str);
  return res.replace(glue, '');
}

const joined = joinStrings(', ')(['a', 'b', 'c']);
console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var names = ['Frank','Vincent','Zappa'];

const join = (names, separator) => {
  let str = '';

  for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    str += (str ? separator : '') + names[i];
  }

  return str;
}

console.log(join(names, ' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function joinFunction(arr){
  let string = ''
 for( let char of arr ){
     string += char + ' '
 }
  console.log(string) 
}

joinFunction(['Frank','Vincent','Zappa'])
```